# how to get checkbox bulk value in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i want to get all the details of youtube,so if the user tick the checkbox i want to get the full details of video in javascript,i have done but only i can get first word from the you tube name,
        you tube name,example $name="Geet - Episode 456 - Clip 1 [24th November 2011] *HQ*" 
        so alert(name) is showing only  Geet .why?
        i need full name.
        this is my code:where i have do the mistake.

```
     <?php

     $watch="youtubelink";
     $thumbnail="youyubeimage";
     $val="somevalue";
     $name="youtubename";
     //eg:$name="Geet - Episode 456 - Clip 1 [24th November 2011] *HQ*";
    $results=$watch.",".$thumbnail.",".$val.",".$name;
     ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" class="addbtn" value=<?php echo $results;?>  />
```

this is my js:

```
   function chkbox()
      { 
      $('[name^=checkbox]:checked').each(function() { 
     var ckballvalue=($(this).val());   
     var fields = ckballvalue.split(/,/); 
     var link = fields[0];
     var thumbnail = fields[1];
     var name = fields[3];
     //var description = fields[4];
     var categ = fields[2]; 
    alert(name);
     var data = {
     action: 'my_action',
     link:link,
     thumbnail:thumbnail,
     name:name, 
     categ:categ

};
```

Comment: Why are you passing around home-made CSV data when there's `json_encode()` available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html you are generating from PHP needs to have quoted attributes:

```
value="<?php echo $results;?>"

// which will end up as:
value="Geet - Episode 456 - Clip 1 [24th November 2011] HQ"
```

That is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" class="addbtn" value="<?php echo $results;?>" />
```

Otherwise you have:

```
value=Geet - Episode 456 - Clip 1 [24th November 2011] HQ
```

So the `value` attribute only goes as far as the first space. (If you use "View Source" in the browser you'll see the difference.)